# Python: which is a fast way to find index in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, find, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following

```
df = 
    a   ID1         ID2         Proximity
0   0   900000498   NaN         0.000000
1   1   900000498   900004585   3.900000
2   2   900000498   900005562   3.900000
3   3   900000498   900008613   0.000000
4   4   900000498   900012333   0.000000
5   5   900000498   900019524   3.900000
6   6   900000498   900019877   0.000000
7   7   900000498   900020141   3.900000
8   8   900000498   900022133   3.900000
9   9   900000498   900022919   0.000000
```

I want to find for a given couple `ID1-ID2` the corresponding `Proximity` value.
For instance given the input `[900000498, 900022133]` I want as output `3.900000`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If this is a common operation then I'd set the index to those columns and then you can perform the index lookup using `loc` and pass a tuple of the col values:

```
In [60]:
df1 = df.set_index(['ID1','ID2'])

In [61]:
%timeit df1.loc[(900000498,900022133), 'Proximity']
%timeit df.loc[(df['ID1']==900000498)&(df['ID2']==900022133), 'Proximity']
1000 loops, best of 3: 565 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 1.69 ms per loop
```

You can see that once the cols form the index then lookup is 3x faster than a filter operation.

The output is pretty much the same:

```
In [63]:
print(df1.loc[(900000498,900022133), 'Proximity'])
print(df.loc[(df['ID1']==900000498)&(df['ID2']==900022133), 'Proximity'])

3.9
8    3.9
Name: Proximity, dtype: float64
```