# Return a list from an array by providing two more lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, find

I have a dataframe like this:

```
         a     b    c
 2    100.0   0.0  0.0
 23   200.0   1.0  0.0
 44   300.0   2.0  0.0
 65   400.0   3.0  0.0
 86   500.0   4.0  0.0
 107  600.0   5.0 -0.5
 128  700.0   6.0  0.0
 149  800.0   7.0  0.0
 170  900.0   8.0  0.0
```

I want to find for a given list of a and b the corresponding value in c.
For example, given a = [100.0, 600.0, 200.0] and b = [0.0, 5.0, 1.0] I want to have c = [0.0, -0.5, 0.0].

I find an interesting link (see below) but It is only available for unique couple of data such as (100.0, 0.0) and not for list of data. I don't want to make a loop (it will be computationally expensive).

Link : [Python: which is a fast way to find index in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108199/python-which-is-a-fast-way-to-find-index-in-pandas-dataframe)

Someone could help me solve this?

Comment: `df.loc[df['a'].isin(a) & df['b'].isin(b),'c'].tolist()`?

Comment: It’s not clear whether you need any value matching in `a` and `b` or the same position in the list. For example if there was a row `a=200, b=5` would it be returned with your example lists?

Comment: For a = 200 and b = 5, the result will be NaN (but in my case, I hypothesis that there will always be a value of a matching b. What I wanted was to get any value matching a[i] and b[i]. A answer has been given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, creating a `pd.MultiIndex` and then using `reindex` of the zipped lists generating a list of tuples:

```
df.set_index(['a', 'b']).reindex(list(zip(a, b)))['c'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[0.0, -0.5, 0.0]
```